# propensity score matching in MatchIt package

Tags: r

I use the MatchIt package do the propenstiy score in matching

I want to know the "case" match to which "control", how do i do

for example, the first case match to the first control, second case match to the second control, and so on.

Comment: Mmm.. not a greatly documented package IMHO (no vignettes, no examples). If you don't find your answer here, try at this mailing list https://lists.gking.harvard.edu/mailman/listinfo/matchit

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and found some syntax that can help.

**First**, after you open the data set but before you run MatchIt, use the following code (data is your data frame and ID is your identifer):

```
####set rownames to id.
rownames(data) <- data$ID
head(data)
```

**Second**, Run the appropriate matchit syntax into an object, like so:

`M.OUT1 <- matchit(Treat ~ X1 + X2, data = data)`

**Third** run the following code:

```
mm<-M.OUT1$match.matrix
tx<-as.numeric(row.names(mm))
m<-cbind(tx,as.numeric(mm))
m[1:5,]
View(m)
write_sav(data.frame(m),"MatchedPairs.sav")
```

The write_sav line can be modified to fit whatever you are exporting your data into (in my case, SPSS. The write_sav function requires the haven package)